# Can a collection view contain a header on the iPad yet not contain on an iPhone using the same storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView that displays multiple columns on an iPad, but when an iPhone is being using we set the item size so that the collection view resembles a table view and only contains one column. For the iPad, we also display a supplementary view as the header that contains additional information; we do not want to display this for the iPhone though. Is it possible to return a supplementary view for the header on an iPad but return nothing on an iPhone so essentially the collection view has no header on the iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

In the bottom of Xcode window (in Main.storyboard) there is a label with "wAny hAny"
[image: you can see it here]

choose the size you want, for iPhone or iPad and then you can implement different code for each size. So you may delete the code which add the view after choosing the iPhone sizes.